# Laradock, configuring SSL with Nginx on localhost

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, laradock

I've been using Laradock to do my local development for a few weeks now and recently needed to utilise HTTPS in order to get Google to callback to me when integrating social logins.

I develop on Windows using WSL2 and made a change to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 tinker-dev.com
```

Any normal `http` traffic to `tinker-dev.com` routes correctly and I see my application, great!

I did some reading and found that I need an SSL certificate signed by an authority and stumped upon [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert), it looks like it should do the job.  After following the installation I `cd` into the `nginx/ssl` folder which is mounted into Laradocks nginx ssl directory via the `NGINX_SSL_PATH=./nginx/ssl/` `.env` var, and I then ran `mkcert tinker-dev.com localhost 127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0 ::1` to produce a cert and key that could be used to authorise requests from these domains (this produced two files: `tinker-dev.com+4.pem` and `tinker-dev.com+4-key.pem`

I then modified the `default.conf` in the `sites-available` to utilise these certs:

```
    # For https
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tinker-dev.com+4.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tinker-dev.com+4-key.pem;
```

and also modified laradocks `startup.sh` to remove the block which auto generates an SSL certificate on load (if default.crtis not found)

```
#if [ ! -f /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt ]; then
#    openssl genrsa -out "/etc/nginx/ssl/default.key" 2048
#    openssl req -new -key "/etc/nginx/ssl/default.key" -out "/etc/nginx/ssl/default.csr" -subj "/CN=default/O=default/C=UK"
#    openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in "/etc/nginx/ssl/default.csr" -signkey "/etc/nginx/ssl/default.key" -#out "/etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt"
#fi
```

I then started my container and found there were no errors in the log, but any traffic to `https://tinker-dev.com` resulted in no traffic being logged in the access log (http traffic is still logged using the domain)...I also realised that I was just being met with a `403` error for any `https` traffic.

I ran `nginx -T` to check which config was loaded and I can see that it is using my certificate/key and if I do `cat /etc/nginx/ssl/tinker-dev.com+4.pem` it prints the cert, so I'm certain that they are being mounted into the container (same result if I cat the key)

Am I doing anything else obviously wrong  here?  I'm not a devopsy person and this stuff is all relatively new to me.

Comment: are you accessing https://tinker-dev.com via browser?  What if you use curl ?  When you generate self signed certificates the client that makes the request has to trust that certificate or certification should be disabled (not recommended)

Comment: Try to run `openssl s_client -connect tinker-dev.com -port 443 -debug`  and see if the certificate is presented or `openssl s_client -connect  tinker-dev.com:443 -debug`

Comment: @Yan thanks for the suggestion.  It seems that the issue is caused by Docker for windows.  It uses its own CA provided by VMWare which is not signed or trusted, this is rejected before the traffic even enters into the VM, thus no traffic is routed to nginx (hence why I see nothing in my access log)...I'm going to see if there is a way to change that certificate.

Comment: @Yan Docker desktop is proving hard to find where it registers its VMWare cert...probably going to opt for ngrok or something instead as a reverse proxy locally

Comment: I haven't really used docker for windows but why do you think docker intercepts the network traffic?  It should just pass it through to the nginx container.  Are you exposing the ports?  Do you see a time out error or untrusted certificate error?  If you can post docker run command that use would be helpful.  Are you running windows with docker inside of VMware virtual machine?

Comment: @Yan I'm seeing an untrusted certificate error, my browser (and openssl) reports that it is trying to use a cert issued and signed by VMWare (which Docker Desktop seems to use under the hood when running docker within hypervisor.  No traffic on port 443 ever reaches my container, only HTTP traffic, leading me to believe the request is intercepted and aborted pre-emptively)

Comment: You are generating self signed certificate which will not trusted  by the browser by default unless you import it to the browsers certificate trust store.  If possible would you be able to post a screenshot of the certificate info from the browser security tab.  I don't see any info that docker for windows is acting as a reverse proxy and intercepting SSL traffic .. I might be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Being on Windows 10 version 2004, [WSL2 became available](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wsl2-will-be-generally-available-in-windows-10-version-2004/) allowing you to use [Docker Desktop with WSL2](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/).

I also have VMWare Workstation 14.x installed. I had this frustration for several weeks before deciding to--reluctantly--uninstall VMWare Workstation. This immediately solved my issue. I tried reinstalling VMWare however, that caused the issue to reappear. I also tried removing all virtual networks in the Virtual Network Editor but this did not make a difference.

If you check your NGINX container access logs, you will see that NGINX never receives the connection requests that you make over SSL--Oddly, HTTP requests seem to work fine. Also, the browser shows a certificate from VMWare. Unfortunately, I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution to this issue but have not found one beyond uninstalling VMWare Workstation. I hope this at least gets you on the correct track.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that was the exact same thing I ended up doing!  It was extremely frustrating for sure!